# Typescript Cannot read property of 'get' undefined Inheritance problem

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I'm receiving this error when trying to run my code. I have an API base class. I use this a base base method for all the services I might create. I then have a Weather Forecast service that inherits or extends rather from this base class. I create my needed functions based off this and then use my service to implement my Weather Forecast CRUD functionality into my various components.

**ApiBase**

```
export class ApiBase
{
  public ID: any;
  forecast: any = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,  private router: ActivatedRoute)
  {
   
  }

  getWeatherForecast(): Observable<any[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('API/' + this.constructor.name)
  }
}
```

**WeatherForecast.Service**

```
import { ApiBase } from "./ApiBase"

export class WeatherForecast extends ApiBase
{
  
  forecasts: any[];

  get()
  {
    return super.getWeatherForecast()
  }
}
```

**WeatherForecast.Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherForecast } from 'src/WeatherForecast.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-WeatherForecast',
  templateUrl: './WeatherForecast.component.html'
})

export class WeatherForecastComponent implements OnInit
{

  constructor(private service: WeatherForecast) { }

  forecasts: any = [];
  ID = this.forecasts.ID;

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.refreshWeatherForecastList();
  }

  refreshWeatherForecastList()
  {
    return this.service.get().subscribe(data =>
    {
      this.forecasts = data;
    });;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using `@Injectable()` annotation on these services you have, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the inheritance but since the error jut says `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`, I assume your service actually don't have the `Injectable` annotation. Thus, its not provided anywhere in your app unless you're providing it "manually". You should add it like:

```js
import { ApiBase } from "./ApiBase"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherForecast extends ApiBase
{
  
  forecasts: any[];

  get()
  {
    return super.getWeatherForecast()
  }
}
```